# Get SQL to compare databases

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make a Sync App for 2 databases in Delphi using FireDAC. Batchmove is very good, but I don't know how to compare the data before syncing from A to bB.

I found the CleverComponents DataCompare. It is handy. Checking the demo, I found what I need. I can get an SQL statement from the source (Master) and compare it to Target DB. But in my development environment, I didn't find that option, and CleverComponents is not answering my emails or ticket open on their website.

I have attached a picture of the details I need. If anyone has used this component before, please give me a hand with it. Or, is there a component that can do the comparison between 2 databases and works with Delphi 10? That would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer in CleverComponets get this resolve , after i contact with them they answer it and they are very nice and helpful and here the Code for my request

https://www.clevercomponents.com/demo/dbcvcl/samples/DataComparerCustomSQL.zip

thanks alot for them